# EF6 avoid to retrieve stored procedure result set

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

Sorry if this is a silly question :)

Let's suppose that I have a stored procedure that modifies a large amount of data and returns the list of data modified as a `SELECT` statement at the end of the procedure.

Let's suppose that from my .Net client application I do not need that result set (I need it sometimes and sometimes I do not).

**My question**: is it possible to avoid bringing all that data back if I do not need it? I.e., to be sure that the data is indeed NOT transferred to the client.

Thanks

Clarification: the stored procedure performs both an `UPDATE` statement and a `SELECT` statement.

I would like to know if the resulting data set from the `SELECT` statement is always transferred to the client and then discarded if not used. Or, if there is a way to not to transfer it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily achieve this by calling `yourEfContextHere.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand('EXEC spMyProcedure ...')`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Yes, but I will not do the UPDATE directly but instead I will call a store procedure which do both UPDATE and SELECT. I want to avoid that the select result set goes to the client because I do not need that.

Comment: Updated the example to include some sample text for calling a stored proc instead of doing an update.  This method is going to ignore the result of the call regardless of what you're executing in SQL.  It might be worth considering if your existing stored proc still needs to perform both a command and a query.